# LCD interface to Controller

Tags: lcd, interface

I am using 3.2' TFT LCD with touch pad. LCD has pins RD and WR. What is RD and WR pin?

Is WR for RD also ( for both write as well as read )?

Where to connect RD pin of LCD?

Please see attached pinout of LCD.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet is the only real answer.

It looks like this LCD has a combination of interfaces:

- DB0 .. DB15 with RD and WR seem to be a parallel interface (for the LCD??)
- The D_* pins seem to be a serial (SPI-like) interface (for the touch-screen??)
- the SD_* pins seem to be another serial (SPI-like) interface - is this one of thise LCDs with an on-board SD card connector?

A parallel interface with separate RW en WR pins (8080 style) requires that one of those pins is made active to do a read or write cycle. Often an alternative 'format' is provided where one pin selects between read and write, and another pin is activated to do a cycle (6800 style).